# Tkinter - How to make a pop-up frame when a button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm quite new to Python and have little to no idea to what I am doing. I am asking a question in relation to a school project.

I have decided to make a game that is scenario based, like a 'choose your own adventure' sort of thing, and am stuck with how to introduce another frame that can pop-up when clicked. This is my program so far and I would like to know how to introduce a new pop-up frame, not an overlapped frame, but one that pops up whenever the **Start Game** button is pressed.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
win = Tk()
win.title('Survival Game')
win.geometry("500x500")
win.resizable(0,0)
win.config(bg = 'deep sky blue', cursor='pirate')


l = Label (win, fg = 'yellow', bg = 'deep sky blue',  font=('Chinyen',24),text = 'Welcome to Survival')  
l.pack_propagate(0)
l.pack(side = TOP)

a1=Button(win, text = ('Start Game'),font =('Chinyen', 15),bg='grey',fg='yellow', height=2, width=30)
a1.pack(pady=50)

def Quit():
  answer = messagebox.askokcancel('Quit', '      Are you sure?')
  if answer:
     win.destroy()
a2=Button(win, text = ('Exit'), font =('Chinyen', 15), bg='grey',fg='yellow',height=2,width=30, command = Quit)
a2.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

I've read something about a TopLevel widget but am unsure what it is and do not know how it works. I am hoping to discover how to incorporate it into my already existing code.

Comment: If you have 'little to no idea what you are doing', then you should do a basic Tkinter tutorial.

Comment: @nothing: Or maybe start first with a tutorial on Python or programming in general, then a good book on event driven GUI programming and then the specifics of tk/tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the changes to your code.

I have put a command attribute for the "Start Game Button". This Button calls the function "NewWindow". NewWindow, then creates another window (toplevel window).

```
# New window creation

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
win = Tk()
win.title('Survival Game')
win.geometry("500x500")
win.resizable(0,0)
win.config(bg = 'deep sky blue', cursor='pirate')


l = Label (win, fg = 'yellow', bg = 'deep sky blue',  font=('Chinyen',24),text = 'Welcome to Survival')  
l.pack_propagate(0)
l.pack(side = TOP)

def NewPage():
    print("New Page")
    win2 = Toplevel(win)
    win2.title('Survival Game')
    win2.geometry("500x500")
    win2.resizable(0,0)
    win2.config(bg = 'red', cursor='pirate')

    label1 = Label(win2, font =('Chinyen', 15),bg='grey',fg='yellow', height=2, width=30, text="New Window").grid()
    win2.mainloop()

a1=Button(win, text = ('Start Game'),font =('Chinyen', 15),bg='grey',fg='yellow', height=2, width=30, command=lambda:NewPage())
a1.pack(pady=50)

def Quit():
  answer = messagebox.askokcancel('Quit', '      Are you sure?')
  if answer:
     win.destroy()
a2=Button(win, text = ('Exit'), font =('Chinyen', 15), bg='grey',fg='yellow',height=2,width=30, command = Quit)
a2.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Eshita Shukla, it did what it was supposed to and I can now move forward in my project.

Comment: Suggestion: this "helps" the question author in the sense that they can present your work as their own (and undoubtedly violate their academic institutions' rules on academic honesty) but it is not clear they will have learned anything from it, since they have not had to fill in any blanks for themselves.

Comment: Halfer, I have added a bare minimum of three lines. There isn't much to learn about it. But, I'll keep your suggestion in mind, and maybe edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: @Eshita: why call the `NewPage` with a lambda? `command=Newpage` is enough.

Comment: @rioV8, many times it may happen that you want to call the function NewPage with parameters like: NewPage(x).
 In such cases, if you do not use  command=lambda:NewPage(x), your function will be called the moment the Button is created. But, you want the function to be executed after the button is pressed. So, lambda becomes important.

Comment: I have become a multimillionaire software developer since this incident. I will never forget your hurtful and straight up bigot-like comments "halfer" *ptuh*. Get robac (run over by a car) and kill yourself for trying to ruin my motivation and my hustle.